# BTLE: Android as Central and iOS as Peripheral

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can I connect a Nexus 4 (android 4.3) with an iPad mini (iOS 7) using a Bluetooth Low-Energy connection?

- The Nexus 4 should be the central device, running a BTLE app based on the official BLE SDK-sample app.
- The iPad mini should be the peripheral device, running a simple iOS app advertising just a single service with a single characteristic. The Nexus 4 should read this characteristic's value.

If the answer to my question is *yes*, I have another question: since I have not an Apple developer license and my iPad mini is not jailbreaked, I cannot install the iOS app on the iPad mini.

But I have a 2012-macbook pro with bluetooth low energy hardware, can I run the iOS app on the iOS SDK-emulator and be able to connect with the Nexus 4?

Comment: Yes, you can connect two devices from different vendors via BLE. And yes, you can run the iOS app in the simulator on a Macbook Pro and still connect to it from another device.

Comment: Unfortunately running the app in the simulator doesn't work. From the log I see that `CBPeripheralManager` is not powered on. After a quick search here on SO, it seems that the iOS simulator needs an *external* BLE dongle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024608/does-the-iphone-simulator-in-xcode-support-bluetooth-low-energy

Comment: I want to do similar stuff... Can you let me know how to create macbook as ble server and scan it on android using UUID?