# Can you use the CoreBluetooth on Xcode simulator?

Tags: xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have read [Does the iPhone simulator in Xcode support Bluetooth Low Energy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024608/does-the-iphone-simulator-in-xcode-support-bluetooth-low-energy)

I need to establish a connection with `BLE` from the `mac retina` to the `iPad Air` .
Did something has changed and i can now make the connection from the mac ?

How if not, can someone make an app that connect the mac to the `iDevice` if you can't establish the connection from mac to iDevice in simulator ?

Is there a way to do that ?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simulator is not supported any more since iOS7 and XCode 5. You need a real device to test core bluetooth iOS applications. There were too much issues with the simulator so they finally dropped its support.

If you have two iOS devices, then use those for testing. If you have only one, then you can create a Mac app that can simulate the other role. The most efficient way to test highly depends on your application.

Comment: Exactly.creating a Mac app that's what I need,but how can you do that without simulator?

Comment: Simply add the IOBluetooth framework to your Mac App and use the same Core Bluetooth API as you would on iOS. The Heard Rate monitor is a great example from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: again, if the mac can't produce bluetooth signals in simulator, it seems that running another program on that same mac, that is mac targeted, will have the same issue.