# Is it possible to use 2 different devices on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm doing an app that uses bluetooth connection between two devices.

How can I test the connection between two devices ?

Is it possible in Xcode ?

Comment: How can I test the connection between two devices? ...with two devices

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not something you can do with the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread [Does the iPhone simulator in Xcode support Bluetooth Low Energy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024608/does-the-iphone-simulator-in-xcode-support-bluetooth-low-energy). Not the same question, but I think it answers yours. Apparently it was possible at some point but now it's not. You'll have to use two physical devices as far as I know.

Comment: You still wouldn't have been able to run two instances of the simulator on the same computer, right?

Comment: Yes, you can, check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446346/xcode6-run-two-instances-of-the-simulator