# Bluetooth Low Energy USB Dongle in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios-simulator, dongle

I know questions like this one has already been answered, but it seems some stuffs changed since.

Indeed, I just bought a Cirago BTA 8000 (BLE USB Dongle) in order to test a BLE-using app on my iOS Simulator. My app use Core Bluetooth.

But when I run it, my CBCentralManagerState is Unsupported. I think this problem comes from the pairing between iOS Simulator and my dongle. As advised in [this message](http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2012/Feb/msg00012.html) or in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024608/does-the-iphone-simulator-in-xcode-support-bluetooth-low-energy), I opened my terminal and typed `$ sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior="never"`, but it seems nothing have changed (even after a reboot).

Plus, every questions I looked for here or in some other websites were talking about Apple's technical note TN2295, which have been removed since.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the iPhone simulator in Xcode support Bluetooth Low Energy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024608/does-the-iphone-simulator-in-xcode-support-bluetooth-low-energy) - BLE isn't supported in the simulator post iOS 7. You need to test on an actual device

Comment: @Paulw11 not according to the popular answer : 

"The simulator does support Bluetooth Low Energy (4.0) according to this appnote from Apple. The only problem is that even if you have a computer with BLE inside, you will not be able to use the simulator together with it, because (I think) you occupy the availability on BLE for other devices to discover your computer, thereby restricting the functionality of the Mac.

So if you go get yourself a BLE USB dongle you will be able to use it in simulator."

Comment: Read the updated note in the yellow box at the bottom of the accepted answer - also this is the reason you can't find TN2295 - it has been removed by Apple as it no longer applies

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, I see.. So there's no way to test a BLE-using app without a developer license and an actual device ? Thank you

Comment: That's correct. You're welcome.