# Can a real iOS device and Watch Simulator communicate for Testing purposes

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to create a watch app for an existing iOS app.

But I am in a situation that i don't own a apple watch and my existing iOS app will run only on real devices not on simulator.

Is it possible to run the app on the iphone device and test my watch app in the watch simulator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pairing a real iPhone and a Watch simulator is not possible at least at the moment. I make this conclusion because of 3 reasons:

1. A Watch simulator automatically pairs to an iPhone simulator during the installation process.
2. It is not possible to unpair a Watch simulator from the interface at all.
3. Bluetooth is not accessible on a simulator to communicate with real devices. Here's a [proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049342/3242031).