# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ only on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Im sure this is something that will be easy for someone with more objective C experience than me. I did not write this but I am stuck using it.

I have a .h file: bleconfigLibrary with an interface:

```
@interface bleconfigLibrary : NSObject.
```

In a different .m file I have:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BTCommands.h"
#import "bleconfigLibrary.h"
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE                (512)
@implementation BTCommands
bleconfigLibrary *handleRequest;

+ (void)initialize{
   handleRequest = [bleconfigLibrary alloc];
}
```

The problem seems to be:

```
handleRequest = [bleconfigLibrary alloc];
```

When I try to run on a simulator I get the error:

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_bleconfigLibrary
```

But it runs fine on physical devices. If I comment out that section, it runs on the simulator.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined an `@interface` for `bleconfigLibrary`, but you haven't defined an `@implementation` for it in the code you've shown here. The fact that it works on physical devices but not the simulator suggests you're linking a library that defines an implementation, but that library isn't built for simulator. Possibly it's an old-style "fat" library that wasn't built for Apple Silicon. The library would need to be [rebuilt as an xcframework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle). (While the linked page discusses Swift, xcframeworks are applicable to ObjC as well.)

But note that [BLE functionality generally does not work in the simulator anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024608/does-the-iphone-simulator-in-xcode-support-bluetooth-low-energy), so you may prefer to simply not build this code for simulator.

This line is incorrect:

```
handleRequest = [bleconfigLibrary alloc];
```

That allocates memory, but does not initialize the object. While it might "work" (if, for example, the object happens not to need initialization), the correct line here is, assuming ARC is enabled:

```
handleRequest = [bleconfigLibrary new];
```

or equivalently, whether ARC is or isn't enabled:

```
handleRequest = [[bleconfigLibrary alloc] init];
```

As a side note, ObjC classes should begin with an uppercase letter (though it's not mandatory). The normal capitalization convention here would be `BLEConfigLibrary`.

(I'm assuming the `.` at the end of your `@interface` definition is a typo in your question, since it wouldn't compile in ObjC.)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I still get the error but that is all good to know. It is a very old library, looking deeper I think the issue is the library is missing a suitable simulator architecture. Is there a way to use a .a file to build what is needed? I am out of my depth when it comes to C stuff. The .a and .h files are all I have to work with.

Comment: There is no practical way to convert a `.a` file built for one platform into a `.a` for another. The only practical approach is to rebuild the library from source. (For extremely small and simple libraries, and a reasonable expertise in ARM assembly and C, it can be done. I've done it once for a library that held a single function and less than 200 lines of code. But I wouldn't call it a "practical" solution. Even in that case, we finally were able to rebuild it from source.)

Comment: Note that this is true of any binary distribution, not just bare `.a` files. Even xcframeworks, which are quite nice ways to bundle multi-platform binaries, cannot be used on new platforms they weren't built for. Accepting a binary-only package will always make you dependent on the other party to provide you new versions when platforms change significantly. It's usually years between this happening, so folks don't realize the trouble it's going to cause when it finally does happen. Best of luck. It's always a hard spot to be in.